# How to compare two tables using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two arrays like this: `[[word],[number of occurence] , ... ]`

```
Table 1 : [[["web"], 9], [["paris"], 8], [["html5"], 6], [["css3"], 6] ... ]
Table 2 : [[["web"], 2], [["paris"], 3], [["word"], 5], [["class"], 6] ... ]
```

I want to compare table 2 with table 1 and only show words NOT on table 2.

With the example I would have get:

```
Table 2 doesn't have html5, css3
```

Does Ruby have a gem that can do that?

Comment: That's a very odd structure to employ. Why not a Hash with key/value?

Comment: Please read "[ask]". Your question isn't asked well. You're asking for a recommendation for a gem, which is off-topic. You also haven't showed us evidence of effort; Did you search and not find anything that helps? If so, where and why didn't it help? Did you write code? If not, why? If so, show us the minimum code that demonstrates the problem you're having.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 helps explain.

Comment: @tadman is right. Odd structure. If a hash is not used, these arrays could at least be simplified, like `[["web", 9], ["paris", 8], ["html", 6], ["css", 6] ...]`. Adding complexity without some kind of gain is not good at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure used here is quite irregular, but remapping it to something easier to work with isn't hard:

```
def hashify(list)
  list.map do |(word), count|
    [ word, count ]
  end.to_h
end
```

The `|(word), count|` declaration pulls word out of the nested array, it simplifies the code.

Given sample data it works like this:

```
table1 = [[["web"], 9], [["paris"], 8], [["html5"], 6], [["css3"], 6] ]
table2 = [[["web"], 2], [["paris"], 3], [["word"], 5], [["class"], 6] ]

hashify(table1)
# => {"web"=>9, "paris"=>8, "html5"=>6, "css3"=>6}
```

Then you can use this to compute the difference:

```
hashify(table1).keys - hashify(table2).keys
# => ["html5", "css3"]
```

Comment: I've never though about using `|(word)|`.

Answer (score 3):

No need for any gem. [Array difference](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-2D) works just fine, but you need to extract the interesting words first :

```
table1 = [[["web"], 9], [["paris"], 8], [["html5"], 6], [["css3"], 6]]
table2 = [[["web"], 2], [["paris"], 3], [["word"], 5], [["class"], 6]]

def extract_words(table)
  table.map{|sub_array| sub_array.flatten.first }
end

puts extract_words(table1) - extract_words(table2)
# html5
# css3
```

With hashes, it would be easier :

```
hash1 = {"web"=>9, "paris"=>8, "html5"=>6, "css3"=>6}
hash2 = {"web"=>2, "paris"=>3, "word"=>5, "class"=>6}

puts hash1.keys - hash2.keys
# html5
# css3
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you don't need the numerical data, so i would propose a one-line solution to your problem :

```
(table1.flatten - table2.flatten).reject {|elem| elem.is_a?(Integer)}
```

That returns the following array :

```
=> ["html5", "css3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table1 = [[["web"], 9], [["paris"], 8], [["html5"], 6], [["css3"], 6] ]
table2 = [[["web"], 2], [["paris"], 3], [["word"], 5], [["class"], 6] ]

table1.flat_map(&:first) - table2.flat_map(&:first)
# => ["html5", "css3"]
```